# Print NominalDiffTime as hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: haskell, time, formatting

I'm surprised nobody has asked this before, but... How do I trivially print a `NominalDiffTime` as hours, minutes and seconds? (And possibly *days*, if it happens to be that long...)

For reasons unknown, the `Show` instance prints total seconds, which is obviously useless. (How long is 13,055.22 seconds? Is that a few minutes? A day? Half an hour? I have no idea!)

There's the `FormatTime` class, but it doesn't apply to `NominalDiffTime`.

It seems you can use the `floor` method to get total seconds as an actual *number*, but then what do you do with it?

As far as I can tell, `DiffTime` doesn't help either.

There *must* be a way to print time durations sanely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print a `DiffTime` -- which actually represents a duration, and is likely the type you should be using -- by going through `TimeOfDay`. Getting your hands on a `DiffTime` correctly is actually a little bit tricky; you'll need:

- A leap second table. [type documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock-TAI.html#t:LeapSecondTable), [a page with a leap second table](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/leap-seconds-future.html); you'll want to have a way for your program to read this in at runtime, as these change every few months.
- From there, you can use [`utcToTAITime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock-TAI.html#v:utcToTAITime) to convert to `AbsoluteTime`, and
- [`diffAbsoluteTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock-TAI.html#v:diffAbsoluteTime) to get a `DiffTime`, and
- [`timeToTimeOfDay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#v:timeToTimeOfDay) to have the library do your divmod's for you, and finally
- [`formatTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#v:formatTime) to print this.

Comment: Note that this only works for `DiffTime`s of less than a day, if it's more than a day `timeToTimeOfDay` adds the extra time as leap seconds. The question asked about a solution that works for days too.

Answer (score 1):

`floor`[1] gives you (as you say) the number of seconds, which you can then use `div` and `mod` to convert into hours, minutes and seconds.

For example:

```
floor ndt `div` 60 -- minutes, which may be more than 59
floor ndt `mod` 60 -- seconds
```

[1] unlike `fromEnum`, which is a "conversion function" but doesn't convert to seconds, contrary to what the documentation says.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFormatDiffTime :: NominalDiffTime -> String
myFormatDiffTime = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S" . posixSecondsToUTCTime
```

Answer (score 1):

time-1.10 has `formatTime` support for  NominalDiffTime.

`formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S" ndt`

Comment: The question also asked for days, so:

`formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%d %H %M %S" ndt`